# Santa Claus' secret permutation

Tags: protocol-design, secret-sharing, permutation

This December, $N$ friends play [secret santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa): they select a random permutation $\sigma$ of $N$ (without fixed point). For Santa Claus, everyone has to bring a gift to the next person in the permutation. To preserve the magical spirit of the game, each participant should only know the strict necessary (i.e. their image by $\sigma$) until the gifts are disclosed in the end of the month.

However, they cannot meet face-to-face before sharing the gifts and would like to generate a proper $\sigma$. We assume that they can communicate together using any cryptographic primitives. Besides, they have no access to a third-party to help generating $\sigma$.

Is there a distributed protocol to generate a random permutation $\sigma$ among them? Which of the following properties can be guaranteed?

- **Secrecy**: Each participant $i$ should only know $\sigma(i)$, and should have no other knowledge about $\sigma$ (i.e. given the messages sent and received by $i$ and $\sigma(i)$, all permutations $\mu$ with $\mu(i) = \sigma(i)$ should be equiprobable).
- **Secrecy++**: Each subgroup of $k < N - 1$ participants should only be able to recover their respective $\sigma(i)$ if they cheat and share information together (again, all permutations that follow these constraints should be equiprobable given their common knowledge). Note that for $k = N - 1$ the permutation is obviously recovered.
- **Fairness**: Each participant cannot cheat to force the value of its $\sigma(i)$, whatever messages they send. Similarly, they cannot force any other $\sigma(j)$, nor bias the distribution of $\sigma$ as a whole.
- **Fairness++**: Each subgroup of $k < N$ participants cannot bias the distribution of $\sigma$.
- **Validity**: $\sigma$ is without fixed point.

---

The **validity** property can also be replaced by other sets of permutations:

- all permutations ($S_N$)
- the [alternating group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) ($A_N$)
- similarly, a subgroup of $S_N$
- other subsets of $S_N$.

---

Solution for $N = 2$ :

- With validity: there is only one choice of $\sigma$: the transposition.
- Without validity: each participant draws a number $x_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and sends it to the other using a [commitment scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme). Once the messages are received, they open the values. Let $X = x_0 \oplus x_1$ (i.e. modulo 2). If $X = 0$, $\sigma$ is the identity, otherwise it is the transposition.

Comment: Solution for N=3 is similarly easy; the three parties jointly compute a random bit, and that tells them whether the cycle is clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: Yes the validity case for $N=3$ is easy. However, the general case (any permutation of $S_3$) seems non-trivial (if possible?). I updated the statement.

Comment: This is a special case of secure multi-party computation. Any general-purpose MPC protocol can do this, it only suffices to write the permutation-sampling process as a boolean/arithmetic circuit.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is given by Peter Ryan, *Crypto Santa*.  In *The New Codebreakers*, vol. 9100 of *Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, pp. 543-549, Springer, 2016. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-49301-4_33

An earlier version (with Sjouke Mauw and Sasa Radomirovic) can be found at http://hdl.handle.net/10993/25936 (Open access), *Security protocols for Secret Santa*.